# Docker Compose Up - Received Permission Denied

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, dockerfile, permission-denied

I am unable to start a new django/python app with docker. I received permission denied.  I recently bought a new computer and my app I had previously used with docker is working fine.  I then recently tried to build a flask/carmen app but deleted everything that I had loaded. Im not sure if that is effecting my docker containers but my previous app will still do docker compose up and down.  I tried this weekly-finances docker-compose config

```
name: weekly-finances
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: /Users/eleahburman/Desktop/code/weekly-finances
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command:
    - python
    - manage.py
    - runserver
    - 0.0.0.0:3000
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 3000
      published: "3000"
      protocol: tcp
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /Users/eleahburman/Desktop/code/weekly-finances
      target: /code
      bind:
        create_host_path: true
networks:
  default:
    name: weekly-finances_default and the docker compose seems correct.  Here is my yaml file: services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

and here is my docker file:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

I tried deleting every app I had by docker and then cloning and adding an env. I started over my new app. I tried deleting docker and reuploading. I also deleted anything I had added with carmen including what I added to my zhrc file.

Comment: Please add the error output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the permission denied with `docker run` command or `docker-compose up` command, then you have to try it with elevated privileges i.e with `sudo`
just add sudo before your command.

For better clarity to the problem please share the error message/screenshot